# Launching directly Android's contact's aggregation suggestion screen

Tags: android, android-activity, android-contacts

My application displays a list of contacts, which I've verified (in code) that there's at least one aggregation suggestion for each of them.
Once the user clicked on one of these contacts, I'd like to open the built-in activity/screen which asks the user about which contacts he'd like to join the selected contact with.

Partially based on [this example](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.AggregationSuggestions.html), I tried running this code:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{

    ContactInfo selectedValue = (ContactInfo) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
                  
    /*Should give URI for Aggregation suggestion*/
    Uri uri = Contacts.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon()
       .appendEncodedPath(String.valueOf(selectedValue.getId()))
       .appendPath(Contacts.AggregationSuggestions.CONTENT_DIRECTORY)
       .appendQueryParameter("limit", "3")
       .build();

    /*Opens Activity*/
    Intent openContactDetailsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    openContactDetailsIntent.setData(uri);
    startActivity(openContactDetailsIntent);
}
```

Yet, all that happens, is that a general contacts screen is being opened, with a list of all the contacts - instead of the suggested contact only.

Is that even possible? Am I passing the right arguments to the right kind of activity?

Answer (score 0):

You evidently need to use [`ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions.html) class.